# How to display a dropbox from an external js file inside php?

Tags: php

How to display this specific dropdown(country and region) from an external js file??. In a regular HTML form with select and option tags it works perfectly but when using with php it does not.The js file is located in the some folder I am using and it works properly in a regular html file. With php it does not run. Somehow it seems that it is not possible to call the .js file inside the php with select and option

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        </style>
        <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        Select Country (with states):
        <select id="country" name="country" required></select>
        <br>State:
        <select name="region" id="region" required></select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registros">

        <script src="locations.js"></script>
        <script src="locations2.js" language="javascript"></script>
        </form>

        </head>

        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        echo "<tr><form action='' method='POST'>";
        echo "<td><select name='technology'><option>ERP/CRM/EPM/BI</option><option>Cyber Security</option><option>Networking</option><option>Infrastructure</option><option>Big Data/M2M/IoT/Blockchain</option><option>Physical Security</option></select></td>";
        echo "<td><select name='description'><option>VENDOR</option><option>VAD</option><option>VAR</option><option>CUSTOMER</option></td>";

        echo "<td><select id='country' name='country'><option><script src='locations.js'></script></option></select></td>";
        echo  "<td><select id='region' name='region'><option><script src='locations2.js'></script></option></select></td>";   
        echo"</form></tr>";          

        }

        ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: This looks strange to me. Can you clarify how this should work? Please include the referenced `js` files.

Comment: Actually I am reaching a mysqli database (MAMP) which brings me back the selected option previous registered and should open this dropdown menu in order to be possible to update the status. For instance I should be able to pick another country and state and update this form. This js file is a huge file which contains all the countries and states in the world. This is a concatenated dropdown i.e. first I select the country then I select the state in this specific country. For the 'technology' and 'description' select everything is fine since the option tags are locally.  Tks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 2 javascript, you can use the country-region library to ease you development. Check this free library: https://github.com/geodatasource/country-region-dropdown-menu. Hosted library available and you no need to refer locally if you want.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/country-region-dropdown-menu/1.1.0/geodatasource-cr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/geodatasource-countryflag.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
        Country: <select class="gds-cr" country-data-region-id="gds-cr-one" ></select>

        Region: <select id="gds-cr-one" ></select>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tks a bunch Chris.